# dealing with binary file in R

Tags: r, httr

I have a .zip file in R that I received through an httr get request (which involved authentication headers, and whatnot, so I can't just use download.file), but it's all some binary gook in memory.

I want to unzip specific files out of it, but I can't figure out how to do that thing, since the unzip method takes a file path, and not the file data.  For that matter, I can't figure out how to even write it to disk... I can't figure out how to do a single thing with it.

viz:

```
> content(a)
[1] 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 0 ...
```

halp!

Comment: `unzip` function takes a `files` option.

Comment: So you have the zip file read in as a binary file to R memory? If so, the Omegahat package Rcompression might work, but it is a) old and b) does not work in Windows. There's also `memCompress()` in base R, but it does not seem handle zip files (bzip and gzip should work, though).

Comment: Save the result to disk with `writeBin()`. Or save directly with `httr::write_disk()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

tmp <- tempfile()   
GET("http://example.com/file.zip", write_disk(tmp))

df <- unzip(tmp) %>% read_csv()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read specific file out from a zip file please try "unz".

> unz("path to zipfile", "file to extract", "r")